# how can I achieve fields grouping between KafkaSpout and the bolts

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I had been sending messages to Kafka topic, these messages are in JSON in the topic and I am using `KafkaSpout` for fetching the messages from Kafka and sending it to the bolt using shuffle grouping. Now I want to implement fields grouping between `KafkaSpout` and bolt. Please can anyone help me on this. How can I achieve fields grouping between `KafkaSpout` and the bolts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `backtype.storm.spout.scheme` interface, basically it looks something like this:

```
public class FooScheme implements Scheme {

  public Values deserialize(final byte[] _line) {

     try{
           Values values = new Values();
           JSONObject msg = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(new String(_line));
           values.add((String) msg.get("a"));
           values.add((String) msg.get("b"))
           values.add(msg)
        }
        catch(ParseException e) {
            //handle the exception
            return null;
        }

  }

  public Fields getOutputFields() {
     return new Fields("a", "b", "json");}
}
```

and you use it with your spout like this:

```
SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig( ... your config here ...);
spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new FooScheme());
KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
topology.setSpout("kafka-spout", 1).setNumTasks(1);
```

and now you can are ready to use the fields grouping by "a" or "b" or both.

```
FooBolt bolt = new FooBolt();
topology.setBolt("foo-bolt", new FooBolt(), 1).setNumtasks(1)
         .fieldsGrouping("kafka-spout", new Fields("a","b"));
```

**Enjoy**

Comment: I had tried implementing using your code example but I could get the following error ---

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tuple created with wrong number of fields. Expected 1 fields but got 2 fields
        at backtype.storm.tuple.TupleImpl.<init>(TupleImpl.java:55) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]

Comment: @RishiArora the number of fields in the getOutputFields is the same as the number of values in the deserialize?

Comment: public Values deserialize(final byte[] _line) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {
   Values values = new Values();
   JSONObject msg = (JSONObject) JSONValue
     .parseWithException(new String(_line));
   //values.add((String) msg.get("id"));
   values.add(msg);
   return values;

Comment: @Override
 public Fields getOutputFields() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return new Fields("id");
 }

Comment: @RishiArora change the  getOutputFields() to return new Fields("id", "json");  You are returning two fields, the id and the message itself.